# Stating directive templateUrl relative to root

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am currently stating templateUrl relative to the current window location.

```
cvApp.directive('personalDetails', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: '../../Scripts/app/templates/personalDetails.html'
    };

});
```

How can I make templateUrl relative to root of the application? I am looking for something like this:

```
templateUrl: '~/Scripts/app/templates/personalDetails.html'
```

Can AngularJS accomplish this?

Comment: Are you trying this on a webserver or local file system? On a webserver you would just use '/path/to/template'. There is no '~' (user home) in web path resolution.

Comment: I undestand OP did not clarify explicitly the context, but from what I can see that is within an ASP.NET web application. So the '~' relates to the idea of *web application root directory*

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Looks like it's supported. Taken from a [thread on AngularJS Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/Ul0r6-sZbRE/2F-BT52h_V8J):

> the url with "/" prefix is relative to the domain, without the "/"
>   prefix it will be relative to the main ("index.html") page or base url
>   (if you use location in the html5 mode).

This works fine:

```
templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/templates/personalDetails.html'
```

Comment: This worked for me in ASP.NET MVC with the BASE tag once I removed the leading slash from the templateUrl value.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you're trying to do ASP.NET style app-relative paths but client-side. The fix is actually in HTML: add a base tag in the head, like this:

```
<base href="<%= Request.ApplicationPath %>" />
```

Then keep your template paths relative to this, as in

```
templateUrl: 'Scripts/app/templates/personalDetails.html'
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that every other relative URL in the document now has this prefix.

Answer (score 3):

Use '././Scripts/app/templates/personalDetails.html'

it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

angular 4 use webpack as bundler.

```
./ means relative path to current folder



../ means parent folder
```

domain = src

root = src/index

for example below app.component.ts file,
url means xxx.html xxx.css are in the same folder as xxx.ts

```
./ is relative path as current folder

../ is relative path as parent folder

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

[COMPONENT-RELATIVE PATHS IN ANGULAR](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: AngularJS and Angular 4 are different libraries, and not necessarily compatible.