# angular js templateUrl with absolute path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

On the video watch page with the url

> /watch/video_id

, I had a ng app. The directive is shown as below.

```
app.directive('myApp', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'ng-templates/myTemplate.html', 
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      },
      controller: 'Controller'
    };
  });
```

Since the templateUrl is the relative path, it will try to find the template in

> '/watch/ng-templates/myTemplate.html'

which is an error.

I want to put all the templates in the ng-templates folder. But it won't work if the ng app always looks for the relative path. Is there a way to configure the app making it to look for '/ng-template/myTemplate.html'?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you try to add leading slash to templateUrl, like

```
templateUrl: '/ng-templates/myTemplate.html',
```

Comment: yes i tried. but it doesn't work. I thought it was supposed to work according to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887018/stating-directive-templateurl-relative-to-root?rq=1#answer-16887869

Comment: I had a problem when using an absolute url in a directive's `templateUrl`, the test wouldn't work when the $httpbackend was mocked out, it would be hitting a non-existent URL.

Comment: I just had the same issue, your browser was caching the previous (most likely blank) template. Need to do a hard refresh/clear cache to get the new template (why it worked).

Comment: is it possible to assign a value of a variable  like this,
var mypath='http:localhost/testapp/';
templateUrl: mypath+'/ng-templates/myTemplate.html',

Comment: Sir, you've just saved my day! I wish I could upvote more times