# AngularJS - Use absolute URLs with ngRoute templateUrls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have an app where the views are saved in a folder above where `base href` is pointing to, resulting in the app not being able to find the views.

So my folder structure would be like this

```
folder
  index.html
partials
  homepage.html
```

Routing using `ngRoute`:

```
.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/homepage.html'
})
```

So currently, the `base href="project-name"` is causing the app to look for the view relative to the project which is of course incorrect. Even if I do something like `../../partials/homepage.html` it will end up not being able to load the view.

Is there any way to be able to use an absolute URL for this `templateUrl`? So that it is always pointing to the right place.

Comment: Add a trailing slash like this templateUrl: '/partials/homepage.html'

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709405/angular-js-templateurl-with-absolute-path

Comment: well, that's annoying. I was playing around with the slashes on the `base` tag but not he actual views. Thanks buddy.