# Angular.js directive's templateUrl not being found?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angularjs-directive, ejs

I built an angular front-end and am attempting to port it to a Express project, and am having a bit of trouble porting the directives I made.

One of the directives not being found is my navigation elements, which in my `index.ejs` is:

```
<navigation></navigation>
```

The directive in my `angularApp.js` is:

```
app.directive('navigation', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'navigation.html'
  }
});
```

I'm getting an error: `"Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$compile/tpload?p0=navigation.html`

Am I linking the `.html` incorrectly in my directive? I generated the Express project using Express' generator.

Comment: probably it's compiled to navigation.html, have you tried `templateUrl: 'navigation.html'` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stating directive templateUrl relative to root](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887018/stating-directive-templateurl-relative-to-root)

Comment: @IlanFrumer I just tried that and I get a `GET http://localhost:3000/navigation.html [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3ms]` error

Comment: @JonathanWrona you said it's in your views folder right?! so put the relative path like so: `templateUrl: '/views/navigation.html'` it's not relative to the js file it's relative to the browser location

Comment: @DavinTryon I just took a look at that link. I'm wondering more how I am supposed to link a directive template when porting angular to express.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "porting".  Express is a web server and the template is a file it is serving.  The `templateUrl` property is relative to the root of the web site.  So you may need to use the the path `/views/navigation...`.

Comment: Sorry about the terminology. I'm very new to MEAN dev. What I mean is that I built an angular.js front-end, and now I'm trying to get that working with Express.

Comment: I'd recommend first trying to do a raw `GET` for the file.  I don't know much about `.ejs` but it probably runs through a view engine and produces `.html` files.  In fact, you probably don't need an `.ejs` file unless you want to do some server side rendering.  So, I think @IlanFrumer is on the right track with comments above.  Try something like `http://localhost:3000/views/navigation.html` to see if you get a response.  If you do, then try `/views/navigation.html` for the `templateUrl`.