# Angularjs templateUrl file location not found

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

I am locally developing a single page app.

I cannot seem to load an HTML file as a template using a simple custom directive in Angularjs. If I attempt to use raw html using the **`template:`** attribute, it works just fine but I have over 400 lines of code i need to use in this template, and as soon as I try to use **`templateUrl:`** nothing loads. I have tried like 30 possible paths including copying the HTML file to many different locations such as C:/my-customer.html in a desperate attempt, here is my project structure:

```
    App--
        |
        css
        |
        img
        |
        js--
           |
           main.js
           |
           foundation.js
           |
           my-customer.html
        |
        templates--
                  |
                  my-customer.html
        |
        bcf.html
        |
        fluidType.html
        |
        start.html
        |
        my-customer.html
```

Keeping it simple I am using the example from the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) here is my code for the directive (inside main.js with my controller):

```
app.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'my-customer.html'
  };
});
```

again I have tried paths like: `../my-customer.html   ../templates/my-customer.html` and so on but nothing is working for `templateUrl:`, I am on windows with no local web server running if this helps.

Here are some console errors but as a newbie not sure what they mean, I have a feeling I need to run a web server and parse through http.

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Dylan/Google%20Drive/PA/Dev/Grossing%20App/templates/my-customer.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
angular.js:11594 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/Dylan/Google%20Drive/PA/Dev/Grossing%20App/templates/my-customer.html'.
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:87:261
    at m (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:83:133)
    at f (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:80:366)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:112:276
    at l.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:126:84)
    at l.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:123:195)
    at l.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:126:362)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:17:448
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:37:96)angular.js:11594 (anonymous function)
angular.js:11594 Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$compile/tpload?p0=templates%2Fmy-customer.html
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:137:65
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:112:276
    at l.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:126:84)
    at l.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:123:195)
    at l.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:126:362)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:17:448
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:37:96)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js:17:369)
```

New to Angularjs. I have hit a wall in the project and I am completely stuck now.

Comment: Similar issue here, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887018/stating-directive-templateurl-relative-to-root

Comment: Tried using this article before posting didn't resolve my issue unfortunately. I just added the console errors though, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are getting a CORS error. That means the URL of your html and the URL of your webapp are two different things.

Comment: Ah yes, about the CORS error: you should run angular app on some server (for example nodejs server), not statically as it will cause CORS errors

Comment: Thanks, I am copying this project to a linux box and going to finish the project there.

Comment: Ok I can confirm this works running on a web server and NOT locally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It should already be relative to the root.  So, this should work:

```
app.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: '/templates/my-customer.html'
  };
});
```

If that doesn't work, first make sure you can browse your template directory:

`http://localhost/templates/my-customer.html`

You should be able to get the template directly.  Once you find the template, then just remove the host and port.

Comment: you can also remove starting / I think

Comment: Did you try to browse for the template directly?

Comment: yea this loads file:///C:/Users/Dylan/Google%20Drive/PA/Dev/Grossing%20App/templates/my-customer.html

Comment: file?  Are you running in a web server?  You need to be running a web server.

Comment: No just locally on my PC, i think this is my issue, I am going to upload this to a linux box and just continue this project there. I will post a follow up to see if that resolves my issue.

Comment: Your local PC probably has a web server built in.  You should investigate and run it through the server.  Then, all will work as expected.

Comment: Yup it works on a web server, running it locally was the issue.