# SPA url issues after hosting on IIS

Tags: iis, single-page-application

I am developing single page application using AngularJs.

I have hosted my application on IIS.

While deploying the application I have given alias name as `"UI"`

Now, when I browse the application it makes the below URL

`http://localhost/UI#/login` but it should be `http://localhost/UI/#/login`

Also there are links of pages in my application.

e.g.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/#/Page1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#/Page2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#/Page3">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on any link it makes this URL `http://localhost/#/Page1` but it should be `http://localhost/UI/#/Page1`

Can someone let me know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: in local iis it works correct ?

Comment: please try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678950/angularjs-routing-not-working-after-site-hosted-into-iis and let me know

Comment: yes If I run using ``F5`` it works. but after hosting on IIS it doesn't work