# Angular JS routing is showing the file name in the URL (in localhost)

Tags: angularjs, routes, location-provider

I have a website (not a project just website) in visual studio 2010.  Just angular and HTML code.

When I debug using IE I have routing working currently but it is showing the file name of my first page (of my single page app) in the URL like this:
    http://localhost:1349/DP/index.html#/home

Routing works like this but I dont want to see the filename "index.html" or the "#" sign.  I have seen many solutions and tried many things.  None of them worked properly (so I wont post all what didnt work here).

The links to my pages are:

`<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#history">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#coachs">Coachs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#activities">Activities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#calender">Calender</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#fundraisers">Fundraisers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#styletesting">Test Styles</a></li>`

the routing code is:

[(function () {
    'use strict';

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);


// configure our routes
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider


        // catch all go home
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })

        // route for the home page
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl: 'navbar.html',
            controller: 'contactController'
        })


        // catch all go home
        .when('/styletesting', {
            templateUrl: 'styleTesting.html',
            controller: 'styletestController'
        })


        /*
        // happens when nothing specificed
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
        */

        /*
        // not working/finding sites
        // if you don't wish to set base URL then use this
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });        
        */
    }]);]
```

As you can see I have the locationprovider commented out because it is not working.  I tried the   but that did not work either.

With all my playing around with various solutions I either get a 404, my page loads but not the section in the ng-view  page (so header and footer shows up and that is the code in the index.html).

What do I need to do to get this to work without showing the page URL?

NOTE:  I am developing on localhost (IIS included/embeded in Visual Studio 2010, not stand alone IIS), and I will want to deploy this to a web host server under a root domain name.  So it will need to work for to both (so I cant hard code full url paths/etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called pretty URL in angular. You need to do three things.

1) in `app.js` you got to inject `$locationProvider` service and enable `html5Mode` routing. The `html5Mode` routing only works for browsers that support HTML5.

```
app.config(["$locationProvider",
    function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

If you are curious, you can check the browser for the html5 history API. If it is not supported it will automatically fallback to using the hash URL approach. 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

```
if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }
```

2) you need to set the `base` tag in the `head` tag of your index file.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

If you don't want to set the base href tag, you can also do this

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

3) Configuring server settings

*Apache :*

```
RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

*IIS:*

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Where/how do I set those settings in IIS?  Is it in my web.config or in IIS itself?  Becuse I am notusing IIS standalone it is the one inside Visual Studio.

Comment: I had tried most/all of that, I will look again but if you can let me know about the IIS config section (that may be my issue).

Comment: @Brad you got to install url rewrite on IIS first. http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite. Also please look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678950/angularjs-routing-not-working-after-site-hosted-into-iis

Comment: @Brad it is in the web.config file

Comment: I had installed that already (though will it install for the IIS that Visual Studio is using)?  

I made all the changes above (I had already had tried it all that way) and when I go to pages without index.html in the URL  I get a directory listing.

Comment: Ok, I switched to Visual Studio 2013 and made the chnages to the web config and it works fine now!!  It must have been IIS not playing nice (or IIS inside VS  not updated) in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: though I had to comment out/remove these cause VS was generating an error:
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wof2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />

Comment: Yea, I had installed the patch and did all the stuff the same way to make it work.  Only thing I was missing was the config file stuff, but I tried that and it gave me errors when in VS 2010, moved to VS 2013 and worked great.