# angular - different directory structure in prod and dev - how to manage templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am using gulp to minify and copy my html views from dev to prod directories. The issue I am having is that somehow I need to account for the changing directory structure in the templateUrl parameter of my custom directives.

For example if dev and prod look like:

> dev -> js -> views -> view.html

and

> prod -> js -> views -> view.html

my directive would look like:

```
directive = {
    templateUrl = 'dev/js/views/view.html'
}
```

Of course, this works fine in dev but when I build my production app, it does not work...

Is there a standard approach for dealing with this? Do I simply have to give up on having two different view directories (one for dev and one for prod)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Config file, determines if your environment is dev / prod based on some value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tokens to replace your URLs (or other values) at build time. Take a look at the [gulp-token-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-token-replace) node module.

Essentially what you will end up with is

```
directive = {
    templateUrl = {{url}}
}
```

And in your gulp config you change `url` based on the type of build you are doing.

[Here](http://addyosmani.com/blog/environment-specific-builds-with-grunt-gulp-or-broccoli/) is a good article showing how its done gulp and other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Will

```
<base href="/dev/">
```

Work for you? Can you get your server to emit this? so it just works when lifted from one ENV' to another.

Also, you web server/platform maybe able todo this for you, ASP.NET would be "~"

also, have a look at [Stating directive templateUrl relative to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887018/stating-directive-templateurl-relative-to-root)

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Define a constant

```
app.constant('APP_CONFIG', {
   'ENVIRONMENT': 'dev/prod'
});
```

**Directive**

(inject APP_CONFIG in directive)

```
directive: {
   templateUrl: function () {
      return APP_CONFIG.ENVIRONMENT === 'dev' ? '/dev/path' : 'prod/path'
   }
}
```