# Webpack Dynamic public path?

Tags: express, angular, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-dev-middleware

I have an app which runs express js and angular 2 I am using webpack to bundle my modules and webpack dev middleware to run webpack with express.

I have setup express js to have a wildcard route to serve the index.html file however, when I attempt to hit localhost:8080/login the webpack-html-plugin isnt adding in the js and css assets at all.

```
app.get('*', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../../../client/src/index.html'));
}
```

if I hit localhost:8080 (home page) the assets are added correctly I can only guess this is handled by the public path because when I change the public path to /login/ the login route works but the home page doesn't?

Is there anyway to make it serve the assets to other routes?

very similar to [Webpack + Angular2 wrong publicPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091715/webpack-angular2-wrong-publicpath?rq=1)

My [Repo](https://github.com/moshie/documentation) is public so if you wouldn't mind taking a look that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed after many hours of browsing to stumble upon this gem which helped me solve this issue hopefully it helps others too.

https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/issues/145