# Angular - Why won't my ui-view show my template html text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wonder why my template which I refer to in my angular state ('home') won't be shown - in my index.html I included a `<ui-view></ui-view>` tag. Does anyone know?

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('portfolio', ['ui.router']);
```

html:

```
<body ng-app="portfolio">
    <p>hellooooo</p>
    <ui-view></ui-view>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>         
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-beta.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/home/home.js"></script>     
</body>
```

home.js:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/browser/js/home/home.html'
    });
});
```

home.html:

```
<div><p>not working</p></div>
```

Comment: Is there any errors in devloper console?

Comment: Try removing 'home' just ''

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887018/stating-directive-templateurl-relative-to-root Your issue might be the `/` in your `templateUrl` param.

Comment: I think its because you don't have a controller set in the state configuration.  IIRC, a controller is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your router are not able to match `/` url. That's why you have to specify a default state, because not always your url will come with `/`.

Consider forcing a default state like so:

```
$stateProvider.otherwise('/');
```