# Angular templateUrl: MVC Controller Function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio

First of all, thanks for taking your time.

My problem is that I want to get a .cshtml (returned from MVC Controller) as template for my angular site.

At first I created a ASP.Net Core 2.1 Web Application Template: Angular. Second I added a Home Controller in the "Controller" Folder.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

// For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace WebApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The next step was to create a folder named "Home" inside the "Pages" folder. Inside the Home folder I created a razor view called "index.cshtml" just filled with a

```
<h1>This is the Index View</h1>
```

Now I changed the templateUrl in app.component.ts to

```
templateUrl: '/home/index',
```

I saw all of that in a post from stackoverflow. I lost the link but here's the github the guy posted with it: https://github.com/ranjanmadhu/Angular2-101

Now I open my cmd, cd to the path of the project and try to build it via ng build.

Here comes the problem, it throws me this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './/home/index' in 'C:\Users\Myridor\AngularMvcTest\AngularMvcTest\ClientApp\src\app'
```

I hope someone can help me solve the problem.

Best regards, 
Nico aka. Myridor

Answer (score 0):

I never thought of an approach like that (mixing Razor and Angular via the templateUrl). I am not sure if that's a good idea. If you insist though, I think this post may help you: [Stating directive templateUrl relative to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16887018/stating-directive-templateurl-relative-to-root)

Good luck!

Comment: If mixing it via templateUrl is a bad approach I'm open for every other idea :)
Will look into the post u shared and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem it will work too - even angular doesn't encourage this approach - But i have a idea for this problem

Directly map the `index.html` generated from angular to your controller that will just call your `index.html` and you can just use the angular components

I hope this will help - please check the sample below

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
      return PhysicalFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
        "wwwroot", "index.html"), "text/HTML");
    }
```

Your action method should look like this - Directly read the `index.html` and return it as a `PhysicalFile()` from your controller

Finally where do we get this `index.html` when you build your Angular Application it will move all your `js` and `css` to your build folder mapped on your `angular.json` file - so make sure the file path and read the `index.html` file

My `outputPath` in `angular.json` reads as:

`"outputPath": "./wwwroot"` - this is not a traditional way to run your application which needs both the angular build and your MVC build to render the pages but you can use it as a workaround

There is another way to achieve this if you are creating angular project in **.net core 2.0^** you will get Angular template where you can create your application - if you do so it will directly render your angular application using `spa` in **.net core**

At my point of view don't mingle your angular template with your razor `cshtml` it's not a good idea - create your angular app seperatly and use your **API** to fetch data

Hope this helps you - Thanks Happy Coding !!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and helping me, however the approach you  wrote does the opposite of what I want to do (as far as I understand). Yours rendering the angular app from a Controller function. However I want the .cshtml to be rendered as my angular app and my approach was to achieve it with MVC Controller functions because the "return View();" will render it (afaik).

Comment: You just told you are open to any other idea so i have suggested you - No problem thanks

Comment: I don't want to disrespect you or your answer I just wanted to explain what I'm searching for because maybe I didn't do it that well in my question. But I'm considering the part "create your angular app seperatly and use your API to fetch data " :)